# How to avoid the "Intenert Explorer wants to track your physical location" prompt?

Tags: geolocation

I have an html page that uses the Geolocation API and each time the page loads it keeps prompting for permission to "track your physical location".

I wonder if there is a way to avoid this prompt and ALWAYS ALLOW BY DEFAULT this option.

The web browser used must be Internet Explorer 11 and prompts are not allowed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, it's IE, so I wouldn't be particularly surprised if there's some horrible security bug that lets you bypass this, but there certainly isn't by design.

Comment: See Alex Filipovici answer in this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14435585/c-sharp-desktop-application-doesnt-share-my-physical-location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant, the user has to know if they location be used. If you want to avoid this, you can use a IP based geolocation.