# Getting location (GPS) in Windows 8 desktop app (WPF): Not the current location is returning

Tags: c#, windows-8, gps, windows-runtime

I am trying to get the location in a Windows 8 WPF desktop application. The PC has working GPS device.

Issue: Not the current location is returning, instead the last location when a 3rd party location aware application was activated.

I've carefully read the ["Getting location in Windows 8 desktop apps" question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13125793/getting-location-in-windows-8-desktop-apps) it seems to be work but with this "feature" which makes that solution unusable. I do not know if this issue is because I missed something or the original concept missed something or this is because we are trying to hack (using WinRT from a Desktop application)

The issue is strange:

The program works as expected, but... The data returned relates to last time the GPS was used by a third party application for example Microsoft BingMaps. So the returned location is not the current.

The base of the solution [Geo-location on Windows 8* desktop applications using WinRT](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/geo-location-on-windows-8-desktop-applications-using-winrt)

How to use WinRT in a desktop project is described here: [Using Windows 8* WinRT API from desktop applications](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-winrt-apis-from-desktop-applications)

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
   public MainWindow()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       new GpsUtils().UseGeoLocation();
   }
}

class GpsUtils
{
    public async void UseGeoLocation()
    {
        var geolocator = new Geolocator();
        var geoposition = await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync();
        // work with geoposition. The geoposition returning here is not the current position
    }
}
```

Missed I something? Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Comment: first to try rule out the "or this is because we are trying to hack (using WinRT from a Desktop application)" run it in a normal Win8 store app.

Comment: Have you tried to use the Sensor API? http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Windows-7-Geolocation-API-25585fac