# C# "await" error when using WinRT from Desktop app

Tags: c#, geolocation, windows-runtime, async-await

I trying to get my GPS position from a Desktop app, using Windows Runtime, in C#.

I followed [this how-to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj856306.aspx) to set up Visual Studio and [this code sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/apps/br225537.aspx) to create the following trivial code as a C# console app :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using System.IO;
using System.Runtime;
using System.Windows;

using Windows;
using Windows.Devices.Geolocation;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;

namespace GeoLocCS
{
    public sealed partial class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test test = new Test();
            Console.Read(); 
        }
    }

    public class Test
    {
        private Geolocator geolocator;

        public Test()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("test");
            geolocator = new Geolocator();

            this.getPos();
        }

        async void getPos()
        {
            Geoposition pos = await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(pos.Coordinate.Latitude.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

When trying to compile, I get the error :

```
Error 1 'await' requires that the type 'Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation<Windows.Devices.Geolocation.Geoposition>' have a suitable GetAwaiter method. Are you missing a using directive for 'System'?
```

I tried to reference every DLL that I could, like "System.runtime", "System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime", "Windows.Foundation"...

What I am missing?

Comment: Sounds like a duplicate,

I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13125793/getting-location-in-windows-8-desktop-apps might give you a solution

Comment: @RemcoBrilstra I also hoped it would, but no. I tried referencing `System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll`, but still get the error.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out my problem :

- I am on 8.1 so I changed this in the .csproj file (targetingPlatform) instead of targeting 8.0
- After that modification, I could reference "Windows"
- I manually referenced the two following DLLs :

  *C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Runtime.dll*

  *C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll*

Comment: this fixed my problem! everything out there is from 2011 and for windows 8.0, many kudos to you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are On Win8.1 Please Use:

```
<TargetPlatformVersion>8.1</TargetPlatformVersion>
```

and not 8.0.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the existing answers:

I suddenly got this problem with a multiproject solution in WPF (still don't know why). I tried switching between TargetPlatformVersions 8.1 and 10.0, tried using the v4.5- and v4.5.1-System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll, always alternating between BadImageFormatException and FileNotFoundException.

Turned out to be references in some of the app.config-files (not the .csproj-files!). Visual Studio 2017 must have added them at some point and as soon as I removed these entries, the above solutions finally worked.

Comment: You are right, in my case the setting  `<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7"/>` lead to the problem.